# My Galaxy s6 phone won't let me touch at all except for the notification bar

Tags: touchscreen

I opened an app, and then it happened. My whole screen got a little bit darker. Then when I tried to restart it, it wouldn't let me touch it at all! The only part that does let me touch and hold is the notification bar. My battery is at 81 percent, and I don't want to leave it over school! WHAT DO I DO!?

Comment: What app is that? Seems something like a screen overlay, a malware maybe